# Put a nsmutablestring into a other nsmutablestring

Tags: iphone, objective-c

If I have a nsmutablestring, I can set his string with the method setString. But this method only takes NSString, How I can put a nsmutablestring into my nsmutableString. If I do this: mutableStringA = mutableStringB, this will change the pointer of mutableStringA and not his string value, is it true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSMutableString inherits from NSString, that means `-setString:` also works with a mutable string argument.

```
[mutableStringA setString:mutableStringB];
```

Comment: Ok, because when I try this mutableStringA is nill, but this is may be cause by a other things in my apps, thank you